# Clickable imageView on ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, click, android-imageview

I have a listview which should contain some data (text) and an ImageView in each item.
So this is what I do, but it looks that the ImageView is not clickable :

here's a part the layout code :

```
<RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/searchIcone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:background="#c7c7c7"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:src="@drawable/search" /> 
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:onClick="searchVisiter"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/CityCountry"
            android:layout_below="@id/address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000" />
```

and my Java code :

```
final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewEvents);
        lv1.setAdapter(new EventListViewAdapter(EventListActivity.this, records));

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

                Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                JsonObject response = (JsonObject)o;
                ID = response.getString("ID");

                // If the image is clicked (doesn't work)
                final ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.searchIcone);
                img1.setClickable(true);

                img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(EventListActivity.this, ZBarScannerActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });

                // If the list item is clicked (works)
                Intent intent = new Intent(EventListActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Please, do you have any idea about this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you do is setting listeners after clicking item on list - it doesn't make sense.
In method `onItemClick` you actually have `View v`, which was clicked, so you can handle that.

I think you tried to write something like:

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
        JsonObject response = (JsonObject) lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
        ID = response.getString("ID");
        if (v.equals(findViewById(R.id.searchIcone)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(EventListActivity.this, ZBarScannerActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(EventListActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you :) I didn't understand the mechanism very well but I uderstand it now with your code... But apparently it's still not clickable.. Is there anything wrong with the layout since the java code is okay ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `onClickListner` to `getView` method of `EventListViewAdapter`

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ....

    ImageView img1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.searchIcone);

            img1 .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
            Intent intent = new Intent(EventListActivity.this, ZBarScannerActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });


        ....

    }
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem.It is Because when you click on image on listItem ..the `onclick()` Method of ListView is triggered by Default.
The Mistake is you are registering `setOnItemClickListener()` for your listView lv1.
Instead just disable `setOnItemClickListener()` on listView and In your Adapter class `EventListViewAdapter.java`  getView() Method just insert following code:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //your layout inflater code here

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.searchIcone);

            iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
             {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(EventListActivity.this, ZBarScannerActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
               }
             });


        ....

    }
```